# EF Core SQLite How can I seed data with foreign keys

Tags: c#, sqlite, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

How can I add seed data into the `DbSet` and bind it with another `DbSet` record?
With my solution, the `ForeignKey` value has been set right but the `TypeModel` from the `ObjectModel` is always `null`. Also how can I add the objects into the `ICollection`after I created the `ObjectTypeModel` into it or will this be filled automatically from EF Core?

My models:

```cs
    public class ObjectModel : BaseEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; 
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String PreviewImage { get; set; }
        public String  TagName { get; set; }
    
         // Foreign keys---
         public int TypeId { get; set; }
         public ObjectTypeModel TypeModel { get; set; }
         //---
    }

    public class ObjectTypeModel : BaseEntity
    {

        [Key]
        public int TypeModelId { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String PreviewImage { get; set; }
        public String TagName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<ObjectModel> Objects { get; set; }
    }
```

My `OnModelCreating()` from the `DbContext`:

```cs
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                 modelBuilder.Entity<ObjectModel>()
                    .HasOne<ObjectTypeModel>(d => d.TypeModel)
                    .WithMany(dm => dm.Objects)
                    .HasForeignKey(dkey => dkey.TypeId);
    
            }
```

My seeding data method:

```cs
            context.Set<ObjectTypeModel>().AddRange(new ObjectTypeModel[]
            {
                new ObjectTypeModel()
                {
                    TypeModelId = 1,
                    Name = "TestType",
                    PreviewImage = null,
                    TagName = "TestType"
                }
            });
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
                var objectTypeOne = context.ObjectTypes.SingleOrDefault(a => a.TypeModelId.Equals(1));

                context.Set<ObjectModel>().Add(new ObjectModel
                {
                    new ObjectModel() { Name="Test", PreviewImage = "null", TagName = "Test", TypeId = objectTypeOne.TypeModelId, TypeModel = objectTypeOne }
                });
                context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The output when trying to receive the data, where the TypeModel is always `null`.

> {"id":1,"name":"Test","previewImage":"null","tagName":"Test","typeId":1,"typeModel":null,"createdOn":"2020-06-29T23:01:24.744472","modifiedOn":"2020-06-29T23:01:24.744464"}

Answer (score 0):

It can't filled automatically and that's why `typeModel` is null when receive the data.

You need to assemble `ObjectModel`.

The details:

When you do `SaveChangesAsync`, only [`Name="Test", PreviewImage = "null", TagName = "Test", TypeId = objectTypeOne.TypeModelId`] saved in DB.

```
            context.Set<ObjectModel>().Add(new ObjectModel
            {
                new ObjectModel() { Name="Test", PreviewImage = "null", TagName = "Test", TypeId = objectTypeOne.TypeModelId, TypeModel = objectTypeOne }
            });
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Set `ObjectModel.TypeModel` with `ObjectModel.TypeModelId` before returning `ObjectModel`.

```
        public IActionResult GetObjectModel(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var objectModel= await _context.ObjectModel.FindAsync(id);
            if (objectModel== null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var typeModel= await _context.TypeModel.FindAsync(objectModel.TypeModelId);
            if (typeModel!= null)
               objectModel.TypeModel = typeModel;
               
            return View(objectModel);
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to show me an example of how I could do it? Like what does it mean to assemble the `ObjectModel`? I have no idea >.<